# Error message calling sklearn from python 3.8.2

Tags: python-3.x, import, python-import, logistic-regression, sklearn-pandas

Using this line code: 
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

I am receiving:

\python\python38\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model_logistic.py:938: ConvergenceWarning: lbfgs failed to converge (status=1):
STOP: TOTAL NO. of ITERATIONS REACHED LIMIT.

Increase the number of iterations (max_iter) or scale the data as shown in:
    https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html
Please also refer to the documentation for alternative solver options:
    https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#logistic-regression
  n_iter_i = _check_optimize_result(

I look for an example and it didnt include some iteration setting. Additionally, I saw an example in a older version of python and this error didnt happen

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your problem may be due to a small dataset that you are training. Try adjusting the 'solver parameter in the algorithm.

```
clf = LogisticRegression(solver='liblinear')
```